# Ionic / Cordova - Convert m4a file to flac

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I using cordova-plugin-audio-recorder-api plugin to record an audio file and I get this audio as m4a file.

I want to convert it to flac file, it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to convert this only with javascript.

But you can send it to your server and use ffmpeg

`ffmpeg -i file.m4a -f flac file.flac`